# How to test if all strings in an array are of the same length

Tags: c#

I have an array of strings.
How to test if all elements in this array have the same length ?

Here is what I have so far :

```csharp
public static bool ComparingStrings(string[] words)
{
    bool result = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        string s = words[i];
        if (s.Length == words.Length)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your code is wrong in many respects. it does not compare the lengths of the words with each other, but instead compares the lengths of the words with the length of the word array, i.e., with the number of words. It replaces the previous result with a new one at each iteration, keeping only the last one. The (faulty) if-else could be replaced by the equivalent statement `result = s.Length == words.Length;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted will compare the length of each string (in characters) to the length of the overall array (in number of elements), since `myArray.Length` givees the number of elements in an array, and `"string".Length` gives the number of characters. The process that you have to do is record the length of the first string, and compare that length to every string in the array to see if there are any which are not the same length.

In C#:

```
string[] myArray = new String[] {"four", "char", "word"};
boolean allSameLength = true;
int firstLen = myArray[0].Length;

for (int i = 1; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
   if (myArray[i].Length != firstLen)
   {
      allSameLength = false;
      break;
   }
}
```

This functionality is encapsulated in pm100's response. [.All()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-6.0) will determine whether ever element in an array passes a logical test, and the [lambda operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) is used to pass the logical test to apply (`s.length==Words[0].Length`).

Comment: You can speed up the test by calling `break;` in the if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq it's pretty straightforward:

```csharp
public bool CompareStringLength(string[] words)
{
    return words.Select(w => w.Length).Distinct().Count() == 1;
}
```

A more efficient version (that stop when two distinct length are encountered):

```csharp
public bool CompareStringLength(string[] words)
{
    return words.Select(w => w.Length)
                .Distinct()
                .Take(2)
                .Count() == 1;
}
```

Nota: The expected result when the array is empty is not provided in the question.
If you need `true` in this case, use `Count() <= 1`;

Answer (score 0):

Simple method:

```
    public static bool CompareSetrings(string[] words)
    {
        // Return false is the array is empty
        if(words.Length == 0)
            return false;

        // The var will hold the length  of the first string
        int initialLength = words[0].Length;

        // Iterating trough string array
        for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            // If the length is different, return false
            if (initialLength != words[i].Length)
                return false; 
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `{var length = words.First().Length; return words.Skip(1).All(w => w.Length == length);}`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static bool CompareSetrings(string[] words)
{
    var len = words[0].Length;
    foreach (string word in words)
    if(word.Length != len) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function accepts a string array. It will return true if the array is `null` or there is only 0 or 1 word in the array. If there is more than one word, it grabs the length of the first word in the array then uses LINQ's `All` method to check if all the strings in the array have the same length by comparing each word's length to the length of the first word (`firstWordLength`). It skips (`Skip(1)`) the first word in the array because we use the first word's length so we remove a redundant check.

```
public static bool CheckAllStringLengthsAreEqual(string[] words)
{
    if (words is null || words.Length <= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    var firstWordLength = words[0].Length;

    return words.Skip(1).All(x => x.Length == firstWordLength);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Words.All(s=>s.Length==Words.Length)
```

Use check if all strings have same length as first one. Nite will not work on empty array

Comment: Isn't this comparing the length of each string element with the size of the array?

Comment: need to change to `Words[0].Length`

Comment: But it match the OP code.

Comment: But the OP code is wrong! It does not work as expected.